# Exact value of $\sin(10°)$ : is my method a good one?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

So some time ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710117/math-for-fun-finding-the-exact-value-of-sin10-unicodexb0) question on finding the exact value of the sine of ten degrees. While I did get the wrong answer, I was wondering if I would be able to get the correct value of the sine of ten degrees using the method that I had used. Here is my attempt at doing so:$\def\a#1{#1\unicode{xB0}}$

> $$\sin(30\unicode{xB0})$$$$=\sin(\a{10}+\a{20})$$$$=\sin(\a{10})\cos(\a{20})+\cos(\a{10})\sin(\a{20})$$$$=\sin(\a{10})(1-2\sin(\a{20}))+2\sin(\a{10})\cos(\a{10})\cos(\a{10})$$$$=\sin(\a{10})-2\sin^3(\a{10})+2\sin(\a{10})-2\sin^3(\a{10})$$$$=3\sin(1\a0)-4\sin^3(1\a0)$$Now, letting$$1\a0=\dfrac x3$$$$3\sin(1\a0)-4\sin^3(1\a0)\gets3\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)-4\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)$$Now, we set what we have gotten equal to $\sin(x)$:$$\sin(x)=3\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)-4\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)$$

Then, we put this into a cubic formula situation:$$4\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)-3\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)+\sin(x)=0$$$$\dfrac{\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)}{\dfrac14}-\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)}{\dfrac13}+\sin(x)=0$$$$4\sin^3\left(a\right)-3\sin(a)+\sin(3a)=0$$Now here's something that I then found out when writing this out:$$4\sin^3(x)-3\sin(x)\equiv-\sin(3x)$$$$\therefore-\sin(3x)+\sin(x)=0$$$$\implies-\sin(x)+\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)=0$$But I realized that this might be wrong, so I went back to the equation and did this:$$4\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)-3\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)+\sin(x)=0$$Now, according to De Moivre's Formula:$$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$$Now you may be asking, how does this relate to the exact value of $\sin(10\unicode{xB0})$ when you're already doing the route of the cubic formula solution? Here's how:

We don't *need* to use the cubic formula. Instead, we expand what we have *using* De Moivre's Formula so then we can plug in $30$ for $x$ and then simplify to get the exact value of $\sin(10\unicode{xB0})$, and here's how we do that:$$4\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)-3\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)+\sin(x)\equiv-4i\left(i\sin^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)\right)$$$$-\left(-3i\left(i\sin\left(\dfrac x3\right)\right)\right)+\sin(x)$$$$\equiv-4i\left((\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^2(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))\right)^\frac13+4i\cos^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)$$$$-\left(-3i\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right)^\frac13\right)-3i\cos\left(\dfrac x3\right)+\sin(x)$$$$\text{Which can be rearranged as }-4i\left((\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^2(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))\right)^\frac13$$$$+4i\cos^3\left(\dfrac x3\right)+3i(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^\frac13-3i\cos(x)+\sin(x)$$Now plugging in thirty for $x$ and simplifying, we get$$-4i\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3+i}2\right)^\frac13-2i\sqrt3+3i\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3+i}2\right)^\frac13-\dfrac{3i\sqrt3}2+2.5\equiv\sin(10\unicode{xB0})$$

---

---

### My question

---

---

Is my solution for the value of $\sin(10\unicode{xB0})$ correct using the method that I have used here, or what could I do to achieve the solution/achieve it more quickly?

---

---

#### Mistakes I might have made

---

---

1. The expansion using De Moivre's Formula
2. Simplifying the expression after expanding using De Moivre's Formula

Comment: If I typed it in correctly, Wolfram Alpha simplifies your result to about $2.67365 - 7.04699i$, which can't be correct.

Comment: Near the top (line 4), it looks like you wrote $1-2\sin 20^{\circ}$ for $\cos 20^{\circ}$. Those are not equal.

Comment: I have changed your previous title "But could I have found the correct value of the sine of ten degrees using the method that I had originally used?" into a more synthetic one "Exact value of $\sin(10°)$ : is my method a good one ?". Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah, that seems like it would be better

Comment: Look here :https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115315/1183190